# Are there thermovision cameras available to hobbyists?

Tags: heat, camera, instrumentation

Years ago, while investigating a short, it came to me that using a thermal vision camera would help an electrical engineer in a lot of situations. Checking it then, such devices were prohibitively expensive, especially for a hobbyist like me.

Recently I saw the "Mµ Thermal Camera" campaign, so there's some movement in that direction. Also, technologies keep improving, and I'm wondering now - are there any affordable thermal vision cameras that are suitable for EE stuff (like finding shorts, analyzing heat issues, checking for unexpected problems, etc — the Mµ guys seem to be focused in a different direction)? Anybody played with such technology to report on pros and cons?

To clarify - I'm not looking for shopping options. More interested in the general state of the market.

Comment: Well the Mu thermal project was an utter disaster (the indiegogo at least).  It was plagued by utter lack of transparency, lack of response and communication from the creators, and lack of fulfilled promises.  Terribly behind schedule, I think it's been about 2 years now and they originally promised something like 6 months. Even a year and a half ago, paranoia began to appear that the project was either fake or just wouldn't succeed. I got my refund probably a year ago when I knew I still could.

Comment: Today, read the comments and you'll find quite a few people up in arms because the creators have seemingly stopped responding and giving out refunds (I imagine they've lost quite a large portion of the money they originally obtained) They have still yet to deliver on really any promise they have made, and have only recently actually shown a real device while people for the last 2 years requested some sort of proof their work was indeed real.  Sorry, I know that was a bit of a rant.

Comment: But to answer your question, there are several other options popping up now, such as the FLIR One, and Seek thermal, which both look like decent products for fairly reasonable price. So yes, interest is popping up in this area. I believe the Flir One and Seek thermal both beat the supposed Mu in specifications.  Surprisingly, I think the Seek is actually the highest in on-paper specs and also the cheapest.

Comment: EEVblog has a bunch of videos where they show various FLIR offerings in use or tear them down. I recommend taking a look, even if they end up being out of your price range.

Comment: There's apparently a sensor array designed for automotive applications that is pretty good and not too expensive (disruptively so). But lenses are still an issue (very expensive).

Comment: Lenses are made from Germanium.

Comment: How do we define "for the hobbyists"? I know people would spend £10k on kit for their hobby, and others who baulk at the idea of more than £50. There is Flir ONE, which is under £300, and there is quite a collection of others out there for under £500 (I'll let others do the currency conversions). In my limited knowledge, quite a lot of the makerspace and hackerspace places have them available too.

Answer (score 0):

Low resolution thermal imagers are available on eBay at quite low prices. Resolution is not great, but I have used them for imaging and measuring hot spots on boards

Comment: This question is from 2014, back then there weren't that many options :) For myself I have long since purchased the Seek Thermal and I'm happy with it, it's been very helpful in a few occasions.

Comment: @anrieff I knew I had to use one when I burned my finger on an inductor. Strangely, it was still in spec for temperature